# How to use multi expression methods in Entity Framework query

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I use same EF query multiple times in my application so I need something like this:

```
private Expression<Func<Student, bool>> StudentIsActive()
{
    return (x) => !x.IsDeleted && x.ItemsNumber > 0 && x.Sort > 0 && x.Status == StudentStatus.Active;
}

private Expression<Func<Student, bool>> StudentIsBusy()
{
    return (x) => x.Mode == ModeType.Busy && x.Jobs.Count() > 0;
}
```

I want to use same logic in multiple of my queries, like:

```
 var students = context.Orders.Where(x => StudentIsActive() && StudentIsBusy()).ToList();
```

Does any one have any idea about this? how could I use **AND** or **OR** logic between expression methods?

Comment: If you only need to `And` them together, just add another `Where` clause, for example: `context.Orders.Where(StudentIsActive()).Where(StudentIsBusy())`

Comment: @DavidG Thanks, good solution for AND

Answer (score 0):

I am not in home so I cant test itt buy I think you can transport these methods into extensions methods of IQueryable like this:

```
  public static class Ext
    {
       public static IQueryable<MainActivity.Student> StudentIsActive(this IQueryable<MainActivity.Student> @this)
        {
            return @this.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted && x.ItemsNumber > 0 && x.Sort > 0 && x.Status == StudentStatus.Active);
        }

        public static IQueryable<MainActivity.Student> IsBusy(this IQueryable<MainActivity.Student> @this)
        {
            return @this.Where(x.Mode == ModeType.Busy && x.Jobs.Count() > 0);
        }

    }
```

And use it like:

```
context.Orders.StudentIsActive().IsBusy().ToList();
```

Comment: This only does "and" but not "or", it's also no different than my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

I usually find the easiest way to `And`/`Or` `Expression`s together is to use [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx). Once you've referenced that library you can do this:

```
//Or
var orPredicate = PredicateBuilder.Or(StudentIsActive(), StudentIsBusy());
var orders1 = context.Orders.AsExpandable().Where(orPredicate);

//And
var andPredicate = PredicateBuilder.And(StudentIsActive(), StudentIsBusy());
var orders2 = context.Orders.AsExpandable().Where(andPredicate);
```

Comment: Could the person who downvoted this please explain?